# Is it possible to make a round widget in Kivy (With only python)

Tags: python, kivy

```
# Create the button to confirm the input
self.confirm_button = Button(text="Click Me!",
                             size_hint=(0.3, 0.3),
                             radius=[(20, 20), (20, 20), (20, 20), (20, 20)]
                             )
```

I tried doing this just for the heck of it (but unsurprisingly it didn't work)